# how to add role='columnheader' and aria-sort attributes on <th> instead of <span> element

Tags: html, material-ui, wai-aria, material-table

I'm using MaterialTable and I'm passing a `columns` array in for it to handle setting up the columns and the column header based on the `title` and `sorting` fields, among others. The `sorting` field is what tells it the column is sortable.

However, when a column has the sorting attribute, the rendered html looks like this in the browser:

```
<th class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-alignLeft MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-4w0mj7" scope="col" style="min-width: 450px; max-width: 450px; box-sizing: border-box; width: calc(7.69231% + 0px);"><span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTableSortLabel-root Mui-active css-dx096b" tabindex="0" role="columnheader" aria-sort="descending" data-testid="mtableheader-sortlabel">Driver Name<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium MuiTableSortLabel-icon MuiTableSortLabel-iconDirectionDesc css-s6n6v6" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="arrow_downward"><path d="m20 12-1.41-1.41L13 16.17V4h-2v12.17l-5.58-5.59L4 12l8 8z"></path></svg></span><span data-testid="material-table-column-sort-order-indicator" style="width: 1em;"></span></th>
```

where the `role='columnheader'` and `aria-sort` attributes are on the `span` element instead of the `th` element. This doesn't comply with accessibility rules and I want this properties to be on the `th` element.

Is there a way to do this without defining a custom header component prop in my MaterialTable?

I tried creating a custom header to solve this, but the logic gets so complex because I'd still like the sorting logic to work like it does when MaterialTable handles it when I pass columns in as an array like so:

```
<MaterialTable
columns={columns}
...
```

Comment: Yes, this is wrong as what you have there, sematically, is a columnheader nested in another columnheader - when a columnheader needs to be nested in a row. Sadly you can't do anything about it other than stop using this library, or file an issue and hope they fix it (the latter doesn't look hopeful as the Github repository apparently hasn't been updated for 9 months).